# Por que angular-cli-ghpages no soporta schematics?

Tags: angular, github-pages

Estoy intentando desplegar un proyecto hecho en Angular a Github Pages siguiendo los pasos de la guía que se encuentra en https://github.com/angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages y en el paso 3 cuando introduzco en la terminal el siguiente commando ng add angular-cli-ghpages me muestra los siguiente:
[image: Me dice que encontró angular-cli-ghpages, pero que no soporta schematics]

Aún así continuo con el siguiente paso de la guía que es ng deploy --base-href=repositoryname y coloco el nombre del repo en el lugar indicado y me lanza la consola el siguiente error:
[image: Error: argumento descononocido]

Noten que probé con diferentes nombres.

También intenté ng deploy solamente y me dice lo siguiente:
[image: Dice qeu no encuentra una carpeta especifica a donde apuntar]
A continuación selecciono la opción **Github Pages** y lanza nuevamente el error de la primera imagen:
[image]

**Nota:** Este mismo problema me sucede tanto en Windows, como en Linux y no he podido finalmente desplegar el proyecto, supongo que es por este problema.

Answer (score 1):

> Asi es al ejecutar  ng add angular-cli-ghpages -->Package
> "angular-cli-ghpages" was found but does not support schematics
> Para poder desplegar la aplicación debido al problema anterior con angular-cli-ghpages
> lo uso de esta forma en Angular 14
>
> > porque no se
> > puede agregar mediante ng add a ese paquete con capacidades
> > de implementacion y asi usar luego ng deploy

1.Creo un repositorio cuyo nombre tenga estas características nombreUsuario.github.git

2.Creo  un proyecto en github al que llame gh

> 3.Creo proyecto en V.S.C al que llame angular-gh
>
> 4.git remote add origin https://github.com/nestdanchia/gh.git
>
> 5.ng build --base-href "https://nestdanchia.github.io/gh/"
>
> 6.npx angular-cli-ghpages --dir=dist/angular-gh
>
> Te dirá que debe instalar angular-cli-ghpages lo aceptas.
>
> 7. te confirmara mediante Successfully published via angular-cli-ghpages! Have a nice day!
>
> 8.Ir a github en settings seleccionar Pages en theme chososer aunque ya esta seleccionadi seleccionar nuevamente mediante change theme
> Cayman

9.si vas al link donde tu aplicación se publico la veras
[nestdanchia.github.io/gh/](https://nestdanchia.github.io/gh/)

Otra forma descripta en angular.io
[Ver Deploy to GitHub Pages](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

> > En versiones anteriores de Angular con los pasos que indicas si se puede Ejemplo con Angular 12
> > En esas versiones si puede modificar al angular.json y publicar en github pages

Ejemplo repo:[repositorio](https://github.com/nestdanchia/angular12-ghpages)
despliegue:[despliegue](https://nestdanchia.github.io/angular12-ghpages/angular12-ghpages/)

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-merge": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular-merge",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-merge:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-merge:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-merge:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "deploy": {
          "builder": "angular-cli-ghpages:deploy"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "angular-merge"
}
```

> Modifica el "outputPath" y el builder

Comment: Gracias nestdan! Logré desplegar el proyecto siguiendo la guía de Angular.io, debo admitir que no he probado su solución, pero le agradezco por su atención y también porque encontré dicha guía por usted. Lo que me pasa ahora es que no se visualiza ninguna imagen después de desplegar, sin embargo en el servidor local si. Esto me pasó con los dos proyectos de preuba que desplegué. Si tiene alguna sugerencia es bienvenida. Tampoco logro que salga el favicon.

Comment: ya logré que saliera el favicon.